# Is a long delay between hiring and start date normal?

Tags: management, new-job, background-check, new-hires

About 3 and a half weeks ago I accepted a seasonal, entry level position at a fitness organisation. Since then, I haven't received any information about my start date or job training. On the two occasions that I asked, the hiring manager said they were waiting for my employee ID, which should "come through any day." Does it really take this long to get a new hire working, or are they just keeping me for when they actually need more employees? Should I start looking for work elsewhere?

Comment: When a company really wants to start someone fast they can get it done same day...

Comment: In the future, remember that you only have a job when you have a signed offer in hand. That's the only moment where you can stop looking for a job, because before then, you still might not have a job.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It ***can*** be "normal," but usually they have that later start date defined up front.  Accepting an "offer," and then hearing nothing but excuses for almost a month, with no tangible action?  No, that's not usual for a real, legitimate position.

Usually "accepting a position" includes a written portion from the company, that includes the details of employment, including pay rate, etc.

If you haven't received one, then, yes, start looking for an actual job, and not just a vague promise of one, as well as asking for the details in writing, to confirm the agreement between you two of an accepted employment offer.  Insist that you need one in writing.  If you didn't have a formal, detailed written offer, you really didn't accept anything of substance.  If they keep delaying and deflecting, than hopefully your re-started job search will have you in a position with someone who has their act together, before the wait (which may never turn into a start) becomes more damaging to you, financially and professionally.

Hope they turn it around quickly, so this doesn't turn into a hard lesson-learned.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions. Good to know I shouldn't just keep waiting around

Answer (score 1):

If I were you, I'd keep looking.  I'm sure that if you'd received a formal offer letter, you would have shared that information with us.  A formal letter would have the information you're asking about.  Lacking that, and the fact that the job is seasonal, your information might have been thrown into a pool of other applicants deemed qualified as hire-able but as "overflow".. i.e. they get a high demand, then they call you; if they don't get busy, then you just don't get called back.  If you've pressed for information and received a B.S. answer, expect B.S. behind the scenes.

Sucks!

Comment: 'as hire-able but as "overflow".. i.e. they get a high demand, then they call you; if they don't get busy, then you just don't get called back.' or if one of their hires turns out to be incompetent/decides to quit, or other similar scenarios - but importantly, there are plenty of scenarios in which OP _never_ gets that call.