# New employer is delaying the Job offer which needs work visa

Tags: job-offer, job-change, career-switch, visa

I was interviewed four months back and offered a work contract two months ago. This job requires me to migrate to a European country. Initial date of joining was 1st of September. When I am serving my notice period, I came to know that company is not applied for a Visa yet due to few changes in their policy. They asked me for contacts for the background check, and I gave it to them. I felt they are giving me all kind of excuses to delay the visa application.

I extended my last date at the current company, but the new employer is not giving any hint about what the final date will be. I'm worried because they didn't tell me about the visa until I asked them. The contract dates are not respected by the company, and I felt unprofessional. Is it better to push them for a decision or look for other opportunities? What rights can do have in this case?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is a long delay between hiring and start date normal?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/92159/is-a-long-delay-between-hiring-and-start-date-normal)

Answer (score 6):

> Is it better to push them for a decision or look for other
>   opportunities?

You should do both.

Tell them that you are concerned that any potential delay would leave you without a job for a while. Ask for a firm start date.

Meanwhile, keep looking for other jobs. Apparently you may not have a firm commitment here.

> What rights can do have in this case?

Probably none. But you may need to consult a lawyer familiar with the new locale to be sure.

Comment: Joe, thanks for the advice. As I got the bad taste, I rejected the offer, as I got multiple offers locally. My current employer is more than happy if I stay back. I took that decision because I don't want to take any surprises after relocating.

Answer (score 6):

You should type into Google "***how long does it take to get an employment visa in [X]***" and see if what they're telling you passes any sort of sanity test.

HR might think they could start the process [Y] days in advance if it normally takes [Y] days, or they might simply have dropped the ball.  The 1st of September is 10 days from now.  If it takes months to do this and they haven't started then you don't have a job.

Certainly call them and try to get hard deadlines for when you can expect things to happen... but it's unclear whether you should believe them.

It's probably time to look **seriously** for a job.